# High AUC and 100% recall, but precision and F1 are low

Tags: machine-learning, precision, roc, precision-recall, imbalanced-data

I have an **imbalanced** dataset which has 43323 rows and 9 of them belong to 'failure' class, other rows belong to 'normal' class. I trained a classifier with **100% recall and 94.89% AUC** for test data (0.75/0.25 split with stratify = y). However, the classifier has **0.18% precision & 0.37% F1 score**. **I assumed I can find better F1 score by changing the threshold** but I failed (I checked the threshold between 0 to 1 with step = 0.01). Also, it seems weired to me that usually when dealing with imbalanced dataset, it is hard to get a high recall. **The goal is to get a better F1 score**. What can I do for the next step? Thanks!

(To be clear, I used **SMOTE to upsample** the failure samples in training dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Getting 100% recall is trivial in fact: just classify everything as 1.

Is the precision/recall curve any good? Perhaps a more thorough scan could yield a better result:

```
probabilities = model.predict_proba(X_test)    
precision, recall, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(y_test, probabilities)
f1_scores = 2 * recall * precision / (recall + precision)
best_f1 = np.max(f1_scores)
best_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)]
```

Comment: I also plotted the precision & recall plot, and the result is very bad. The area under the precision-recall curve is almost 0. 
One question in mind is I used 3-fold cross-validation and the cv performance is good (training set is up-sampled by using SMOTE), but the performance on test is very bad. (I understand the performance on cross-validation might a bit overfitting, but in this case the performance dramatically dropped). I have no idea how to proceed.